# Why is Odata Olingo JPA producer working, even though error log displays?

Tags: java, mysql, odata, olingo

I'm new in Java EE servlet world has basic idea. I tried to implement an example Odata producer by using Olingo library. I follow [this tutorial](http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server#jive_content_id_1_Create_a_dynamic_web_project_in_Eclipse)

So I can see correct output for emplist.svc/$metadata.

It uses following libraries:-

JPA: Add EclipseLink and JPA Persistence

> eclipselink.jar
>   javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar

Database: Add MySQL connector

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar

OData: Add Apache Olingo OData libraries

> olingo-odata2-core-incubating-1.0.0.jar
>   olingo-odata2-api-incubating-1.0.0.jar
>   olingo-odata2-api-annotation-incubating-1.0.0.jar
>   olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core-incubating-1.0.0.jar
>   olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api-incubating-1.0.0.jar
>   javax.ws.rs-javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar

Service: Other libraries required

> cxf-api-2.7.5.jar
>   cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.7.5.jar
>   cxf-rt-core-2.7.5.jar
>   cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.5.jar
>   cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar

***As far as  I understood this example doesn't use any Spring framework or library. How come it is complaining about Spring and still working.***

When I launch it to Tomcat 7. I can see following error log:-

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61 May 08, 2015
>   11:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/Users/masum/practice/hibernate/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesorderprocessing.app/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class log4j:WARN No appenders could be
>   found for logger (org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   May 08, 2015 11:10:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on
>   classpath May 08, 2015 11:10:44 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring root WebApplicationContext May 08, 2015 11:10:44 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext INFO: Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization started May 08, 2015 11:10:44 AM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup
>   date [Fri May 08 11:10:44 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy May
>   08, 2015 11:10:44 AM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] May 08, 2015
>   11:10:44 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)

**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)**